# How to write multiple variables using fprintf in short way in matlab?

Tags: matlab, printf

my code is something like this

```
a= [2 4 5 8 6 7 88 9]
b= [12.8 41.3 13.7]
c= [16 18 20 10.1 17.5 49.5]
fprintf(out_file,'%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %f %f %f %d %d %d %f %f %f',a,b,c)
```

is it possible to write the conversions (`%d....%f`) in `fprintf` in a shorter form instead of repeating it so many times?

Or is there any other command that I can use to write the same into files?

Answer (score 5):

This answer assumes you **don't need trailing decimal zeros**. That is, `[4 4.1]` should be printed as `4 4.1`, not as `4 4.10000` or `4.00000 4.10000`.

Let

```
a = [2 4 5 8 6 7 88 9];
b = [12.8 41.3 13.7];
c = [16 18 20 10.1 17.5 49.123456789]; % example with 9 decimal figures
```

- You can **dynamically build the format string** using [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`strjoin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html). Also, you can use the [format specifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) `%g`, which automatically prints integer values without decimals:

  ```
  fprintf(strjoin([repmat({'%g'},1,numel(a)+numel(b)+numel(c))]),a,b,c)
  ```

  gives

  ```
  2 4 5 8 6 7 88 9 12.8 41.3 13.7 16 18 20 10.1 17.5 49.1235
  ```
- If you need to **specify a number of significant figures**, avoiding trailing decimal zeros:

  ```
  fprintf(strjoin([repmat({'%.8g'},1,numel(a)+numel(b)+numel(c))]),a,b,c)
  ```

  gives

  ```
  2 4 5 8 6 7 88 9 12.8 41.3 13.7 16 18 20 10.1 17.5 49.123457
  ```
- If you can do with a trailing space, you do not need to build the format string with repetition, as `fprintf` can automatically **recycle** it for all the inputs:

  ```
  fprintf('%.8g ',a,b,c)
  ```

  gives

  ```
  2 4 5 8 6 7 88 9 12.8 41.3 13.7 16 18 20 10.1 17.5 49.123457
  ```

Comment: how can i add a string to the above eg. d= 'data points  : ' 
i want to be written as follows :
data points : 2 4 5 8 6 7 88 9 12.8 41.3 13.7 16 18 20 10.1 17.5 49.123457

Comment: @AlFer You only need to prepend that string. For example, with the second approach it would be `fprintf(['data points: ' strjoin([repmat({'%.8g'},1,numel(a)+numel(b)+numel(c))])],a,b,c)`. With the third: `fprintf(['data points: ' sprintf('%.8g ',a,b,c)])`

Answer (score 3):

```
% Input.
a = [2 4 5 8 6 7 88 9];
b = [12.8 41.3 13.7];
c = [16 18 20 10.1 17.5 49.5];

% Concatenate inputs.
x = [a b c];

% Find integer values.
intidx = (floor(x) == x);

% Set format string.
formatstring = char((intidx.') * '%d ' + (not(intidx).') * '%f ');
formatstring = reshape(formatstring.', 1, numel(formatstring));

% Output.
sprintf(formatstring, x)
```

Comment: good answer, but you have a typo in the last line: _printf_ does not exist in MATLAB, you have to use _**f**printf_ ;-)

Comment: @Hoki Thanks for hint, I meant to use `sprintf`, the s got lost somewhere. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@HansHirse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55061416/8239061) is excellent.  Another alternative using `repmat` below.  Could have compacted the code a bit but left in its current form for accessibility.

** Alternative Approach: ** `repmat`

```
a= [2 4 5 8 6 7 88 9];
b= [12.8 41.3 13.7];
c= [16 18 20 10.1 17.5 49.5];

fmtInt = '%d';    % format for integers
fmtFloat = '%f';  % format for floating point

fmtA = [repmat([fmtInt ' '],1,length(a)-1) fmtInt]
fmtB = [repmat([fmtFloat ' '],1,length(b)-1) fmtFloat]
fmtC = [repmat([fmtFloat ' '],1,length(c)-1) fmtFloat]

fmtstr = [fmtA ' ' fmtB ' ' fmtC]    % desired format string

% Can call fprintf() or sprintf() as required using format string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
cellfun                            ...
(                                  ...
    @(f,v) fprintf(outfile, f, v), ...
    {'%d ', '%f ', '%d ', '%f '},  ...
    {a, b, c(1:3), c(4:6)},        ...
    'UniformOutput' , false        ...
);
```

You can also use loop:

```
fmt = {'%d ', '%f ', '%d ', '%f '; a, b, c(1:3), c(4:6)};
for f = fmt;
    fprintf(outfile, f{:});
end
```